# No valid tracking code found for property

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing below error when login to Analytics service, but everything worked fine until today, what could be the reason? how to resolve this?

Error:

> No valid tracking code found for property example's default URL https://example.com. Make sure your pages are tagged with a supported version of the tracking code

Thanks in advance,
Ranuk

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are experiencing some of the same symptoms found in this [Google Analytics forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/8ca-E7bJelM). From what I can gather sometimes the error is falsely triggered.

Since your error message has **https://** in the URL are you sure that your site can be accessed from **https://**?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a SEO plugin that I installed to my Wordpress site *after* I had verified my page on Google Analytics site. I solved the issue by going to Google Webmaster Tools section in my plugin settings, and following the instructions to claim the site again.